# Wordpress Wocommerce Copy text to clipboard

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, text, copy, clipboard

I want to add a quick copy option next to the address, phone and e-mail information on the order detail page in the WooCommerce admin panel. Can anyone help?

[image]